# Wildfly10 hsqldb module not installed, datasource configuration ko

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb, wildfly-10, java-ee-8

Hi I try a JEE8 security web application example found here: https://github.com/swhp/javaee-soteria

I would to install it in Wildfly10 (jboss 7+), with Cargo Maven 2 plugin, andwith
HSQL database (instead of Postgres).
App Running with cargo:run

So i modified a pom.xml, adding pluginand dependency for hsqldb like above:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>id.swhp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-soteria</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Security API Soteria -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.soteria</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.security.enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Omnifaces, develop JSF never easier without Omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>javaee-soteria</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>wildfly10x</containerId>
                        <zipUrlInstaller>
                            <url>
                                http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip
                            </url>
                        </zipUrlInstaller>
                        <dependencies>
                            <!--<dependency>-->
                                <!--<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>-->
                                <!--<artifactId>jdbc6</artifactId>-->
                            <!--</dependency>-->
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <copy>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/configuration/</file>
                                <todir>
                                    ../../installs/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration
                                </todir>
                                <configfile>true</configfile>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                            <copy>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/configuration/</file>
                                <todir>../../configurations/wildfly10x/configuration</todir>
                                <configfile>true</configfile>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                                <copy>
                                    <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/modules/</file>
                                    <todir>../../installs//wildfly-10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base</todir>
                                    <configfile>true</configfile>
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                            <copy>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/configuration/</file>
                                <todir>
                                    ../../installs/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration
                                </todir>
                                <configfile>true</configfile>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                        </files>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.start.jvmargs>
                                -Xdebug
                                -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000
                                -Xnoagent
                                -Djava.compiler=NONE
                            </cargo.start.jvmargs>
                            <cargo.jboss.modules.dir>modules</cargo.jboss.modules.dir>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.jboss.management-http.port>9050</cargo.jboss.management-http.port>
                            <cargo.servlet.users>admin:admin</cargo.servlet.users>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I copy the configurations files (standalone.xml) and hsqldb driver(jar) + relative module.xml inmy jboss dir, and I configure plugin to copy to wildfly installation dir (in target):

myprojectdir\src\main\jboss\configuration\standalone.xml
myprojectdir\src\main\jboss\modules\org\hsqldb\main\module.xml
myprojectdir\src\main\jboss\modules\org\hsqldb\main\hsqldb-2.4.0.jar

satandalone.xml :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

    <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.2">

        <extensions>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
        </extensions>

        <system-properties>
            <property name="spring.profiles.default" value="namingEnvironment:external"/>
            <property name="spring.profiles.active" value="namingEnvironment:external"/>
        </system-properties>


        <management>
....
....
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
                <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                        <connection
url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                        <driver>h2</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                            <password>sa</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/soteria" pool-name="SOTERIA" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/SOTERIA</connection-url>
                        <driver-class>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver</driver-class>
                        <driver>hsqldb</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                        <driver name="hsqldb" module="org.hsqldb">
                            <datasource-class>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource</datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
.... (i can't copy all lines of code..)

    </server>
```

module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hsqldb">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hsqldb-2.4.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

when i run command "cargo:run" the above module.xml and hsqldb jar are copied to

```
cargo\installs\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\hsqldb\main
```

But,I get this Exceptions, what's my mistake? Thanks!

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:53,427 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("jdbc-driver" => "hsqldb")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [org.hsqldb]"
..
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver (version 2.4)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,108 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = javaee-soteria.war_org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver_2_4
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,558 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "javaee-soteria.war")]) - failure description: {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria"],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.persistenceunit.\"javaee-soteria.war#soteria\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria]",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.persistenceunit.\"javaee-soteria.war#soteria\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria]"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "Services that were unable to start:" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".CdiValidatorFactoryService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".WeldStartService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.AccountStore.START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.AccountStore.WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.AccountStore.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.PbkdfGenerator.START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.PbkdfGenerator.WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.PbkdfGenerator.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.SHAGenerator.START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.SHAGenerator.WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.SHAGenerator.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenScheduler.START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenScheduler.WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenScheduler.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenStore.START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenStore.WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.TokenStore.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"id.swhp.javaee.soteria.application.servlet.AuthenticationFilter\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"id.swhp.javaee.soteria.application.servlet.AuthenticationFilter\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"managed-bean.java.util.Date\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"managed-bean.java.util.Date\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener\".START",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".component.\"org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener\".WeldInstantiator",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".deploymentCompleteService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".jndiDependencyService",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.deployment.unit.\"javaee-soteria.war\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.module.javaee-soteria.javaee-soteria.env.\"id.swhp.javaee.soteria.business.account.boundary.AccountStore\".em",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.module.javaee-soteria.javaee-soteria.env.\"id.swhp.javaee.soteria.business.security.boundary.TokenScheduler\".em",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.module.javaee-soteria.javaee-soteria.env.\"id.swhp.javaee.soteria.business.security.boundary.TokenStore\".em",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./javaee-soteria",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./javaee-soteria.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         ],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "Services that may be the cause:" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         ]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,562 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("data-source" => "SOTERIA")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ]) - failure description: {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb"],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/soteria is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "org.wildfly.data-source.SOTERIA is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,569 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ("data-source" => "SOTERIA")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ]) - failure description: {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/soteria is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "org.wildfly.data-source.SOTERIA is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "org.wildfly.data-source.SOTERIA is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "Services that were unable to start:" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.SOTERIA",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.soteria"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         ],
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "Services that may be the cause:" => [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria"
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         ]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "javaee-soteria.war" (runtime-name : "javaee-soteria.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name : "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.SOTERIA, service jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/soteria] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jdbc.soteria (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee-soteria.war#soteria".__FIRST_PHASE__, service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee-soteria.war#soteria"] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 15:01:58,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9050/management
```

this is my persistence file descriptor in resources\META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="soteria" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jdbc/soteria</jta-data-source>
        <!-- TODO: parameterize this -->
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: try <jta-data-source>jdbc/soteria</jta-data-source> instead of   <jta-data-source>java:jdbc/soteria</jta-data-source>

Comment: No it doesn't work, "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable [
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/soteria is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb]"
and Others errors

Comment: Where did you place the module.xml and the JAR?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i place thre in my-absolute-project-path\target\cargo\installs\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\hsqldb\main

Comment: jboss-cli show me only h2 driver and no hsql installed! :[standalone@localhost:9050 /] /subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "driver-name" => "h2",
        "deployment-name" => undefined,
        "driver-module-name" => "com.h2database.h2",
        "module-slot" => "main",
        "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
        "driver-xa-datasource-class-name"...
           }]
} I have also replace java:jdbc/soteria with java:jboss/jdbc/soteria in standalone and in persistence.xml but nothing changed..

Comment: Do you get any exceptions about the driver when starting wildfly?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i'm adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml in META-INF and WEB-INF and i get this Exceptions now:
org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'hsqldb-2.4.0.jar' at path 'hsqldb-2.4.0.jar' (position: END_TAG seen ...<resources><resources>\\r\\n        <resource-root path=\"hsqldb-2.4.0.jar\"/>... 28:49) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file"}

Comment: @SimonMartinelli then Then I try to copy module by hand without plugin and running wildfly i get another exceptions: ERROR [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error during the deployment of java:jboss/jdbc/soteria: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031103: At least one connection property must be defined for datasource-class: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I remove from my standalone in <driver> the <datasource-class> and add <driver-class> now i get this exception:
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It work! Then I'm adding module dependency to eclipselink 2.7.1 (beacuse wildfly use hibernate as default persistence provider)and im setting in persistence descriptor the <provider> org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>.Add module to deployment-strucuture xml (in my application) but i can't understand why cargo copy modules Archives but when i try to open with 7Zip it says "Corrupted".. \:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164400/discussion-between-robyp7-and-simon-martinelli).